# Postgres: multiple selects that exclude results from previous ones

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of widgets that have a number of connections with potentially overlapping modes. For instance, widget A may have 10 connections, and 5 of those can run in mode A and all 10 can run in mode B. A connection has at least one supported mode. I'm trying to figure out how to design a query that returns a list of devices that support a given number of connections with particular modes.

The simplified schema looks like this:

```
table widgets
  id
  name

table connections
  id
  widget_id

table modes_connections
  connection_id
  mode_id

table modes
  id
  name
```

I need to return widget_ids that satisfy filters similar to:

```
2 connections with mode A AND
2 connections with mode B AND
1 connection with mode C
```

I can't just join everything together because the first filter for mode A must exclude those results from the other filters, similarly the mode B filter must exclude those results from the mode C filter, etc.

Also, I'm not sure how to prioritize results so connections with the least number of modes have preference. Consider the case where there are 3 connections that support modes A, B, C and two that support mode B. In the filter example above, the mode B filter should select the only-mode-B connections, allowing the A,B,C mode connections to satisfy the requirements for modes A and C.

I'm totally at a dead end. Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated. Redesigning the schema is also an option.

Comment: Could you add sample data and the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> create table widgets (id int, name text);
> create table connections(id int, widget_id int);
> create table modes_connections(connection_id int, mode_id int);
> create table modes (id int, name text);
> ```

> ```
> insert into widgets values
> (1, 'widget1'), (2, 'widget2'),(3, 'widget3'),(4, 'widget4');
>
> insert into connections values
> (1, 1),(2, 1),(3, 1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(9,1),(10,1),
> (11, 2),(12, 2),(13, 3),(14, 3),(15, 4);
>
> insert into modes_connections values
> (1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),
> (2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3),(2, 4),(2, 5),
> (2, 6),(2, 7),(2, 8),(2, 9),(2, 10),
> (3, 5),(3, 6),(3, 7),(3, 8),(3, 9);
>
> insert into modes values 
> (1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'C'),(4, 'D');
> ```

> ```
> select w.id, w.name, m.id, m.name, count(c.id) connections
> from   widgets w
> join   connections c
> on     c.widget_id = w.id
> join   modes_connections mc
> on     mc.connection_id = c.id
> join   modes m
> on     m.id = mc.mode_id
> group by w.id, w.name, m.id, m.name 
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name    | id | name | connections
> -: | :------ | -: | :--- | ----------:
>  1 | widget1 |  1 | A    |           2
>  1 | widget1 |  2 | B    |           2
>  1 | widget1 |  3 | C    |           2
>  1 | widget1 |  4 | D    |           2
> ```

You can add more conditions to the WHERE clause using the format:

```
exists (select 1 from x where id = wdg.id and ......)
```

> ```
> ;with x as
> (
> select w.id, w.name, m.id mode_id, m.name mode_name, count(c.id) connections
> from   widgets w
> join   connections c
> on     c.widget_id = w.id
> join   modes_connections mc
> on     mc.connection_id = c.id
> join   modes m
> on     m.id = mc.mode_id
> group by w.id, w.name, m.id, m.name 
> )
> select id, name
> from   widgets wdg
> where  exists (select 1 from x where id=wdg.id and mode_id = 1 and connections = 2)
> and    exists (select 1 from x where id=wdg.id and mode_id = 2 and connections = 2)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name   
> -: | :------
>  1 | widget1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c1d986c0c2d678e8f23a58c771b19124)*

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. I don't think it covers the preference selection though. See this dbfiddle: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8ddedd6d210448cd38fe0c79faef6690
 I would expect the last query to return both widget1 and widget2, since both can support that combination of modes.

Comment: I'm glad to help, please upvote the answer if you like it.

Comment: Playing with this a bit, I do see an issue - connections are counted more than once in the filter. Is there an easy way to fix that? Example: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f8d7df949feb2f0f4c22afa5d45e6cb0
Here I query on >= 2 mode A and >= 1 mode C and get both widgets. There are connections that satisfy each of those filters (1 and 2 in widget 1), but I'm really looking for independent connections (3 ports total, which none of the widgets satisfy). I couldn't figure out how to ensure the connections "counted" in one filter aren't "counted" in another.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear to me, do you need connections(A + C) >= 3 or connections(A) = 3 OR connections(B) = 3 or connections(A) >= 2 AND connections(B) >= 3?  Could you rewrite the formula?

Comment: Again, I really appreciate the help! Connections can only be counted once. If one connection supports modes A or B or C, and another connection only supports B, then a query for 1xA and 2xB should return nothing, since it's not possible for 2 connections to satisfy that constraint. There will probably need to be a sort involved here, since mode filters should be satisfied by the connections with the fewest modes. In this example, 1xB and 1xA works, but only if Conn1=A and Conn2=B, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the requirements, but you can always use `where exists () and not exists()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm stumped myself.  Is this what you're looking for?

```
select * from (
  select id, name, acnt, bcnt, ccnt,
         row_number()
         over (partition by id order by (acnt+bcnt+ccnt)) RN
    from (
      select w.id, w.name,
        (select count(*)
           from modes m, mode_connections mc,
                connections c
           where m.name = 'A'
             and m.id = mc.mode_id
             and mc.connection_id = c.id
             and c.widget_id = w.id )  ACNT,
        (select count(*)
           from modes m, mode_connections mc,
                connections c
           where m.name = 'B'
             and m.id = mc.mode_id
             and mc.connection_id = c.id
             and c.widget_id = w.id )  BCNT,
        (select count(*)
           from modes m, mode_connections mc,
                connections c
           where m.name = 'C'
             and m.id = mc.mode_id
             and mc.connection_id = c.id
             and c.widget_id = w.id )  CCNT
         from widgets w
    )
    where acnt >= 2 and bcnt >= 2 and ccnt >= 1
) where RN = 1
```